# Qt5 install problem ubuntustudio 22.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu-studio, qt5

The short version of the question: where is qt5 installed on Ubuntu Studio 22.04?

The long version of the question can be seen unanswered [here on the SuperCollider forums](https://scsynth.org/t/qt5-install-problem-ubuntustudio-22-04/5756): essentially I am trying to build SC from source and am hitting some problem that I think may be related to the location of qt5.

(I should say that I'm not a programmer but do have a basic ability to get around linux in the terminal.)

Thanks

Comment: Please do a search : `apt-file search Qt5Config.cmake` or on-line https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=Qt5Config.cmake → → `qtbase5-dev`

Comment: Thanks, but not any further forward. The suggestion you make is to search for the location of a file called `Qt5Config.cmake` but the error message says `By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`... which would seem to indicate needing a file called `FindQt5.cmake`. No such file appears in the online search you suggest?

Comment: I'm getting errors when trying to run the query using `apt-file` locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SuperCollider, build example Ubuntu 22.04
https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider/blob/develop/README_LINUX.md

Basic build requirements :
`sudo apt install build-essential git cmake libsndfile1-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libfftw3-dev emacs libudev-dev`

Qt5 : no qt5-default, now only available for 20.04 and earlier.
Originally qt5 was (is) optional, therefore no `FindQt5.cmake`.
`sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev`

```
git clone https://github.com/supercollider.git
cd supercollider/
git submodule update --init --recursive
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -DNATIVE=ON ../
make
.
[100%] Linking CXX executable timetag_test
[100%] Built target timetag_test
```

Comment: Thanks, but same error still:

`
CMake Error at QtCollider/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested
  version 5.7) with any of the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.

`

Comment: sorry can't figure out how to format that as code!

Comment: Suggest : Start from scratch, and follow my build example strictly ...

Comment: Sorry, still same error. I started with `rm -rf SuperCollider/` to clear everything out. The only change I made is with this error `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/supercollider.git/' not found` case error I think, it needs to be `SuperCollider`

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/SuperCollider/SuperCollider.git`

Comment: oh rats, sorry, I missed a step `sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev` that's what fixed it! Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add:

`sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev`

Resolved an issue opening FreeSurfer 7.3's FreeView software on Ubuntu 22 LTS.